# EF Core "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.[table name]' with unique index [index]

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following entities defined

```
public class Product
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public int UnitOfMeasureId{get;set;}
   public UnitOfMeasure UnitOfMeasure{get;set;}
   public int SaleUnitOfMeasureId{get;set;}
   public UnitOfMeasure SaleUnitOfMeasure{get;set;}
}

public class UnitOfMeasure
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string ShortName{get;set;}
   public string Description{get;set;}
}
```

So, I have various UnitOfMeasure rows in the database. I inserted a product and everything was fine. The problem arises when trying to insert a second product and throws the following exception:

> SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Products' with unique index 'IX_Products_PurchaseUnitId'. The duplicate key value is (1).
>   The statement has been terminated.

Why is this happening?

```
// inserting UnitOfMeasure
var uoms = new List<UnitOfMeasure>
{
  new UnitOfMeasure {Name="Kilogram", ...},
  new UnitOfMeasure {Name="Ounce",...}
}

foreach(var uom in uoms)
  _dbcontext.Add(uom);
_dbcontext.SaveChanges();

// Inserting Product
var product = new Product(UnitOfMeasureId = 1, SaleUnitOfMeasureId = 1);
dbcontext.Add(product);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();

// this operation throws the exception
var otherProduct = new Product(UnitOfMeasureId = 1, SaleUnitOfMeasureId =1);
dbcontext.Add(otherProduct);
dbcontext.SaveChanges(); // this line throws the exception

// Offending table constraint

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_UnitsOfMeasure_SaleOfMeasureUnitId] FOREIGN KEY([SaleUnitOfMeasureId])

REFERENCES [dbo].[UnitsOfMeasure] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_UnitsOfMeasure_SaleUnitId]
GO
```

Comment: The clue is in the error message. How are you generating your data for input? How are the classes defined in terms of primary keys? How are the products and units linked. What is your code to add new data? Sample data, expected results and actual code please.

Comment: You scripted out the FK constraint.  It does not look like the "offending" "IX_Products_PurchaseUnitId" constraint, which is a unique-index.  Keep fishing around in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
```

The Id is defaulting to zero.

So your second .Add/SaveChanges is hurting you there.

try this:

```
var product = new Product(Id = 111, UnitOfMeasureId = 1, SaleUnitOfMeasureId = 1);
```

and

```
var otherProduct = new Product(Id = 222 ,UnitOfMeasureId = 1, SaleUnitOfMeasureId =1);
```

and try again (you keep most of your same code..but make the above 2 changes)

If that does not work.

Go to your database and to your table in SSMS. (Sql Server Management Studio)..

Find the constraint: (by fishing around the objects under the table)

```
IX_Products_PurchaseUnitId
```

Right click and do a

> "Script Key (or Constraint) Out" / "Create To" / "Clipboard"

, and paste that into your original question.  That will help figure out the issue rather quickly.

If you don't have database access, you'll have to 'play around' with the values to try and figure out what the index is composed of.

HINT, don't use ambiguous values.

Try this: (repeat same value for SaleUnitOfMeasureId , aka 444)

```
var product = new Product(UnitOfMeasureId = 333, SaleUnitOfMeasureId = 444);
```

and

```
var otherProduct = new Product(UnitOfMeasureId = 555, SaleUnitOfMeasureId =444);
```

then try this:

Try this: (repeat same value for UnitOfMeasureId , aka 777)

```
var product = new Product(UnitOfMeasureId = 777, SaleUnitOfMeasureId = 888);
```

and

```
var otherProduct = new Product(UnitOfMeasureId = 777, SaleUnitOfMeasureId =999);
```

Comment: Same error. The "Id" property is defined in the database as being "Identity", autoincrementable with step of 1, and IdentitySeed=1 (this is the start value). So "Id" will be 1 for the first product, 2 for the second, ....., etc.

Comment: Ok, so that's and IDENTITY.  So you're ok there.  I added a "if that does not work" append to my answer.

Comment: If it is defined in the db as identity, but ef does not know it, it will insert the 0. You neeed to tell ef that it is a db level identity column.